# Function won't unbind after I run fancybox with a boolean being used

Tags: jquery, fancybox, unbind

I am trying to get a button to stop flashing after the fancybox has closed. I have tried every way I know and I am not sure why it is not unbinding. Here is the code:

```
    var clicked = true;
    var playbtn = $('.playbtn');

    function unpulse(){
       clicked = false;
       playbtn.unbind(pulse);
    }

    function pulse(){
       playbtn.delay(200).fadeOut('slow').delay(50).fadeIn('slow', pulse);
    }

    if (clicked) {
       pulse();
    }else if (!clicked) {
       alert('finally');
     };


     $('.playbtn a').fancybox({
        'type' : 'iframe',
        'transitionIn':'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :'elastic',
         'speedIn':600, 
         'speedOut':200, 
        'overlayShow':  false,
         'onClosed':unpulse
     });
```

Comment: unbind is for event, not function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to remove an event, because that's what `.unbind` does. (Also, your syntax for `.unbind` is not supported, but it's not what you're after anyway.) Instead, just check inside `pulse` whether or not to continue fading. This works because `pulse` is called recursively, so the check is done each time a fade iteration has stopped:

```
function pulse(){
  if(clicked) {
    playbtn.delay(200).fadeOut('slow').delay(50).fadeIn('slow', pulse);
  }
}
```